# Display JSON in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to display JSON output using AngularJS. What would be the best way to do this? Would gridOptions be a good idea? All I want to print is the label/parent's label/parent's parent's label/... till the root in reverse order.

```
   {  
   artifactId:"6450",
   classificationId:6451,
   id:3276,
   hierarchyId:"lp",
   label:"Authorization",
   nodeId:"84",
   parent:{  
      id:3275,
      hierarchyId:"lp",
      label:"Authorize",
      nodeId:"83",
      createdBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
      createdOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
      updatedBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
      updatedOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
      parent:{  
         id:3193,
         hierarchyId:"lp",
         label:"Actions & Verbs",
         nodeId:"1",
         createdBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
         createdOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:17Z",
         updatedBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
         updatedOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:17Z",
         parent:{  
            id:3192,
            hierarchyId:"lp",
            label:"root",
            nodeId:"13190",
            createdBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
            createdOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:14Z",
            updatedBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
            updatedOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:14Z"
         }
      }
   },
   parentNodeId:"83",
   createdBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
   createdOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
   updatedBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
   updatedOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:23Z"
},
{  
   artifactId:"6450",
   classificationId:6452,
   id:3280,
   hierarchyId:"lp",
   label:"Licensee",
   nodeId:"88",
   parent:{  
      id:3276,
      hierarchyId:"lp",
      label:"Authorization",
      nodeId:"84",
      createdBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
      createdOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
      updatedBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
      updatedOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
      parent:{  
         id:3275,
         hierarchyId:"lp",
         label:"Authorize",
         nodeId:"83",
         createdBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
         createdOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
         updatedBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
         updatedOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
         parent:{  
            id:3193,
            hierarchyId:"lp",
            label:"Actions & Verbs",
            nodeId:"1",
            createdBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
            createdOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:17Z",
            updatedBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
            updatedOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:17Z",
            parent:{  
               id:3192,
               hierarchyId:"lp",
               label:"root",
               nodeId:"13190",
               createdBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
               createdOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:14Z",
               updatedBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
               updatedOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:14Z"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   parentNodeId:"84",
   createdBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
   createdOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
   updatedBy:"INITIAL-LOAD",
   updatedOn:"2014-09-12T16:21:23Z"
},
```

SO I have something like :

```
<table>
 <tr ng-repeat='label in labels'> 
<td> label.label </td>
<td> label.parent.label</td>
<td> label.parent.parent.label</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

which I am sure doesnt look right. How do I display all the labels up till the root in reverse? So in this case it would be Root/Action&verbs/Authorize/Authorization

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple scope function that traverses the object tree and constructs an array for each label object:

```
$scope.getAncestorLabelsForLabel = function (labelObj){
    var labels = [];
    while (labelObj) {
        labels.push(labelObj.label);
        labelObj = labelObj.parent;
    }
    labels = labels.reverse();
    return labels;
};
```

Basically, for each label object, which contains the parents, we call this scope method which construct an array of labels.

http://jsfiddle.net/mafohb1d/

Comment: This is exactly what  I would want to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i don't know where you use a json like this?!
but i found it intresting to show, because this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>!!!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        td{
            border: 2px dotted green;
            padding: 4px;
            background-color: #aaa;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MonApp">
    <div ng-controller="CommentsCtrl">
        <!-- all elements in comments ||| ng-repeat do foreach -->
        <table>
             <tr ng-repeat='label in labels'> 
                <td> {{label.label}} </td>
                <td> {{label.parent.label}}</td>
                <td> {{label.parent.parent.label}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>  


    <script>
        // create a object for using angular in this body.document (body ng-app="MonApp")
        var app = angular.module('MonApp', []);
        // create controller    
        app.controller('CommentsCtrl', function($scope){
        // create or get json with some name, here "comments"
        $scope.labels = [
            {
                artifactId: "6450",
                classificationId: 6451,
                id: 3276,
                hierarchyId: "lp",
                label: "Authorization",
                nodeId: "84",
                parent: {
                    id: 3275,
                    hierarchyId: "lp",
                    label: "Authorize",
                    nodeId: "83",
                    createdBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                    createdOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
                    updatedBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                    updatedOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
                    parent: {
                        id: 3193,
                        hierarchyId: "lp",
                        label: "Actions & Verbs",
                        nodeId: "1",
                        createdBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                        createdOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:17Z",
                        updatedBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                        updatedOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:17Z",
                        parent: {
                            id: 3192,
                            hierarchyId: "lp",
                            label: "root",
                            nodeId: "13190",
                            createdBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                            createdOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:14Z",
                            updatedBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                            updatedOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:14Z"
                        }
                    }
                },
                parentNodeId: "83",
                createdBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                createdOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
                updatedBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                updatedOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:23Z"
            },
            {
                artifactId: "6450",
                classificationId: 6452,
                id: 3280,
                hierarchyId: "lp",
                label: "Licensee",
                nodeId: "88",
                parent: {
                    id: 3276,
                    hierarchyId: "lp",
                    label: "Authorization",
                    nodeId: "84",
                    createdBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                    createdOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
                    updatedBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                    updatedOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
                    parent: {
                        id: 3275,
                        hierarchyId: "lp",
                        label: "Authorize",
                        nodeId: "83",
                        createdBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                        createdOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
                        updatedBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                        updatedOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
                        parent: {
                            id: 3193,
                            hierarchyId: "lp",
                            label: "Actions & Verbs",
                            nodeId: "1",
                            createdBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                            createdOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:17Z",
                            updatedBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                            updatedOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:17Z",
                            parent: {
                                id: 3192,
                                hierarchyId: "lp",
                                label: "root",
                                nodeId: "13190",
                                createdBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                                createdOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:14Z",
                                updatedBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                                updatedOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:14Z"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                parentNodeId: "84",
                createdBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                createdOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:23Z",
                updatedBy: "INITIAL-LOAD",
                updatedOn: "2014-09-12T16:21:23Z"
            }
        ];
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is a result:

Authorization    Authorize       Actions & Verbs
Licensee         Authorization   Authorize